# jquery click event fireing off when I attach it with 'on'

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm making an application where I 'have' to enable and disable mouseenter/leave and click on a div frequently. But I've run into a problem where I use the enable function but this will cause it to run prematurely, without the user have clicked anything.

I have a outter div which contain six small divs. When the user clicks the outer outter div the smaller div will get their mouseenter/leave and click event attached whilst the outter div will get its turned off. And then in reverse once a small box is clicked.

below functions disables and enables the events for the divs.

```
function enableHalve(){
            $("#top-wrapper, #bottom-wrapper").on({
                mouseenter: function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $(this).css("background-color", "#00cc66");
                    $(this).css('cursor','pointer');
                },
                mouseleave: function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $(this).css("background-color", "#c0c0c0"); 
                }
            });  

            $("#top-wrapper, #bottom-wrapper").on({
                click: function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                update($(this).attr('id'));
            }});
        }

        function disableHalve(){
            $("#top-wrapper, #bottom-wrapper").off('click');
            $("#top-wrapper, #bottom-wrapper").off('mouseenter').off('mouseleave');                 
            $("#top-wrapper, #bottom-wrapper").css({'cursor' :"default"});
            $("#top-wrapper, #bottom-wrapper").css({'background-color' :"#c0c0c0"});
        }   

        function disableBoxes(){
            $("#one, #two, #three, #four, #five, #six, #seven, #eight, #nine, #ten, #eleven, #twelve").off('click');                
            $("#one, #two, #three, #four, #five, #six, #seven, #eight, #nine, #ten, #eleven, #twelve").off('mouseenter').off('mouseleave');
            for (var y = 0; y < boxes.length; y++) {
                $("#"+boxes[y]+"").css("background-color", "blue"); 
                $("#"+boxes[y]+"").css('cursor','default');
            }
        }

        function enableBoxes(){
            $("#one, #two, #three, #four, #five, #six, #seven, #eight, #nine, #ten, #eleven, #twelve").on({
                click: function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                update($(this).attr('id'));
            }});

            $("#one, #two, #three, #four, #five, #six, #seven, #eight, #nine, #ten, #eleven, #twelve").on({
                mouseenter: function () {
                    $(this).css("background-color", "#00cc66");
                    $(this).css('cursor','pointer');
                },
                mouseleave: function () {
                    $(this).css("background-color", "blue"); 
                }
            });     
        }

This function is triggered from the click event. 

function update(answer){            
            console.log("answer: " + answer);

            if(answer === "top-wrapper" || answer === "bottom-wrapper"){
                console.log("ny test");
                serverRequest(answer);

            }else if(boxes.indexOf(answer) > -1) {
                console.log(answer);
                zeroCount = zeroCount - 1;
                currentAnswerSequence = currentAnswerSequence + answer;
                console.log("Inde zero: " + zeroCount);

                if(zeroCount == 0){
                    //This part here will make the function trigger again, because the click event calls update()
                    disableBoxes(); 
                    enableHalve();
                    serverRequest(currentAnswerSequence);
                    currentAnswerSequence = "";
                }
            }       
        }
```

my html

```
<div id="top-wrapper">
    <div id="one"></div>
    <div id="two"></div>
    <div id="three"></div>
    <div id="four"></div>
    <div id="five"></div>
    <div id="six"></div>                
</div>

<div id="bottom-wrapper">
    <div id="seven"></div>
    <div id="eight"></div>
    <div id="nine"></div>
    <div id="ten"></div>
    <div id="eleven"></div>
    <div id="twelve"></div>             
</div>
```

Comment: You can greatly shrink those huge selectors by instead using `top-wrapper > div, bottom-wrapper > div`

Comment: @4castle yes thanks for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is when the inner divs are clicked, **the event still propogates** up to the outer divs before the handler gets removed. To fix this, change `e.preventDefault()` to `e.returnValue = false;`. In jQuery, this is the same as calling both `e.preventDefault()` and `e.stopPropagation()`.

jQuery objects can be given **custom attributes** using `.data()`. It would greatly simplify your code and speed it up if, instead of adding and removing event handlers, you do a check for if it should run using an if statement on something like `.data("clickEnabled")` or `.data("mouseEnterEnabled")`. Then to enable or disable the events, just set the custom attribute of the jQuery object by using `.data("clickEnabled", false)` or `.data("clickEnabled", true)`.

Comment: I've updated my answer so that you can fix it right *now* without making the switch to using `.data()`.

Comment: thanks alot! Glad to learn some new stuff, have a nice evening.